# Trim a full string instead of using trim() with characters

Tags: php, regex

When using a specific delimiter in a data string, often I want to trim off the last instance of it before exploding.

I have always wondered this:

PHP `trim()` will trim off whitespace, or certain characters. But what if I wanted to trim full strings, like so:

```
$data = 'cookieDELIMITERchocolateDELIMITER';
$data = trim($data, 'DELIMITER');
```

The above won't really work, since it won't trim the string "DELIMITER", but instead trim the characters "D,E,L,I,M,T,R".

What I want is this:

```
$data = 'cookieDELIMITERchocolate';
```

I appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = 'cookieDELIMITERchocolateDELIMITER';
$data = preg_replace('/^(DELIMITER)*|(DELIMITER)*$/', '', $data);

var_dump($data);
// string(24) "cookieDELIMITERchocolate"
```

The regular expression [`^(DELIMITER)*|(DELIMITER)*$`](http://regex101.com/r/uR5iP1) will match 0+ (`*`) instances of "DELIMITER" at the beginning (`^`) of a string or (`|`) the end (`$`) of the string.  [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will take these matches and replace them with blank strings.

---

**Full RegEx Explanation**

```
^                # Matches the start of the string
  (DELIMITER)*   # Matches "DELIMITER" 0+ times, thanks to the *
|                # OR
  (DELIMITER)*   # Matches "DELIMITER" 0+ times, thanks to the *
$                # Matches the end of the string
```

This means it will either match many DELIMITERs at the beginning OR the end of the string.  Since `preg_replace()` does a global match/replace, it will get all occurrences of DELIMITER as long as they are either attached to the beginning or end of the string.

Adding the dot (`^(DELIMITER).*|(DELIMITER)*$`) would match the beginning of the string, followed by DELIMITER, followed by 0+ of any character (`.` matches all).  This would effectively [replace the entire string](http://regex101.com/r/zJ7nH7) if it started with `DELIMITER`.

Comment: Sounds good, just add the dot, right? `^(DELIMITER).*|(DELIMITER)*$` http://regex101.com/r/wJ6vR5

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this to keep from having an empty array element after `explode()`, try this:

```
$array = array_filter(explode('DELIMITER', $data))
```

Comment: Great solution as well.

Comment: @Chris - This would remove all of the `DELIMITER` texts, not just any on the ends of the string.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: yes, if you read the question they want to remove the last delimiter prior to exploding on the delimiter.  So I combined them.