# Trim a full string, not characters - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, trim, data-manipulation

This is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349257/trim-a-full-string-instead-of-using-trim-with-characters), but the answers there were very specific to PHP (and I'm using Redshift SQL, not PHP).

I'm trying to remove specific suffixes from strings. I tried using [RTRIM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RTRIM.html), but that will remove any of the listed characters, not just the full string. I only want the string changed if the exact suffix is there, and I only want it replaced once.

For example, `RTRIM("name",' Inc')` will convert "XYZ Company Corporation" into "XYZ Company Corporatio". *(Removed final 'n' since that's part of 'Inc')*

Next, I tried using a CASE statement to limit the incorrect replacements, but that still didn't fix the problem, since it will continue making replacements past the original suffix.

For example, when I run this:

`CASE WHEN "name" LIKE '% Inc' THEN RTRIM("name",' Inc')`

I get the following results:

"XYZ Association Inc" becomes "XYZ Associatio". *(It trimmed Inc but also the final 'n')*

I'm aware I can use the [REPLACE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html) function, but my understanding is that this will replace values from anywhere in the string, and I only want to replace when it exists at the end of the string.

How can I do this with Redshift? (I don't have the ability to use any other languages or tools here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the trailing  `Inc` by using a regex that anchors the  `Inc` to the end of the string:

```sql
CASE WHEN "name" LIKE '% Inc' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE("name", ' Inc$', '')
```

Note that given the regex will *only* match a string that ends in  `Inc`, the `CASE WHEN "name" LIKE '% Inc'`is not strictly necessary as a replacement can only occur when that is true. However it may give better performance to leave it in as regex operations can be expensive time wise.

A better solution though is to keep the `CASE WHEN` and simply strip the last 4 characters (i.e.  `Inc`) when it matches:

```sql
CASE WHEN "name" LIKE '% Inc' THEN LEFT("name", LENGTH("name")-4)
```

PostgreSQL (Redshift base) demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/N2_ynAqZ)

Comment: is there a benefit to do the `CASE WHEN "name" LIKE '% Inc'` part, and not directly `REGEXP_REPLACE("name", ' Inc$', '')` ?

Comment: @Tom it's not strictly necessary but - given regex operations can be slow - might improve performance to leave in. But there's a more efficient solution anyway, see my edit. Thanks for getting me to revisit this, it needed some improvement.